# Node/Express: Route identifiers for root '/' route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, requirejs

I'm developing a directory app where content is rendered server-side depending on some parameters. My directory is a subapp of other app that is running on appache. I use the reverse proxy to redirect to node when needed.

So, my node root route is this: `http://myapp.com/directory/`

I need to have routes in this format: `http://maypp.com/directory/location/category`

where,
location and category can be anything! (it's user generated content)

My initial thought was that I would be able to do something like this:

```
app.get('/:location?/:category?', routes.index);
```

However, I get the following behavior:
In my `routes.index` after I render the view I have 
`console.log('location: ' + req.params.location + ', category: ' + req.params.category);`

When I navigate to `http://maypp.com/directory/` I get the following:

```
location: css, category: main.css
GET /components/modernizr/modernizr.js 200 69ms - 48.97kb
GET /components/requirejs/require.js 200 69ms - 80.75kb
```

And browser output is broken with the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.js:1
```

And the weirdest thing is that main.js contains rendered HTML page instead of my browser-side js modules.

Another test case:
When I navigate to `http://maypp.com/directory/loc/cat` I get the following:

```
location: loc, category: cat
location: css, category: main.css
GET /components/modernizr/modernizr.js 200 6ms - 48.97kb
GET /components/requirejs/require.js 200 6ms - 80.75kb
location: js, category: main.js
```

and same stuff as above on the browser's side.

In my `layout.jade` I have the following:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/directory/components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/directory/js/main")
```

If I have my route defined without second identifier (like this `app.get('/:location?', routes.index);`), it works fine, but it's not what I need!

====== Answer =========
Moved all of the route handling below static asset handling middleware.

```
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view options', {layout: true});
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.responseTime());
app.use(express.errorHandler());
app.use(express.responseTime());
app.use(require('prerender-node'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
app.use(app.router);

var routes = require('./routes')(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> location: css, category: main.css

This and some of your errors are because your handlers for static content, css, and js are not set up to execute BEFORE app.router. Ordering of middleware in express must be carefully thought through and precise. So first get your middleware order correct so all your static CSs, JS, images, etc are handled before the app.router.

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot! Because of the way I organized my routes I have the following `var routes = require('./routes')(app);`, this was called before the static assets handling. I just moved it down, so it's after app.router! Now it's working.